Having Oauth issues w/ a mern application
I'm currently building my first app for client but I'm experiencing an error while testing the sign in functionality i get:
http proxy error: /api/auth/google
background: I'm using a mern architecture with Firebase google oauth, it was previously working but seems to not be currently i got a link to this doc
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/redirect-best-practices?hl=en&authuser=1&_gl=1*l8w56g*_ga*MTg5NDE0NTUwOC4xNzE5Njk4Mjcw*_ga_CW55HF8NVT*MTcxOTY5ODI3MC4xLjEuMTcxOTcwMDgxMC40MS4wLjA.#signinwithpopup
but dont quite see what in my code needs to change
`
import { GoogleAuthProvider, getAuth, signInWithPopup } from 'firebase/auth'
import { app } from '../firebase';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { signInSuccess } from '../redux/user/userSlice';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function OAuth() {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const handleGoogleClick = async () => {
      try {
        const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
        const auth = getAuth(app);

        const result = await signInWithPopup(auth, provider);
        const res = await fetch('/api/auth/google', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json', // Ensure correct content-type header
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            name: result.user.displayName,
            email: result.user.email,
            photo: result.user.photoURL
          }),
        });

        // Log the raw response
        const text = await res.text();
        console.log('Raw response:', text);

        // Parse the response if it is JSON
        const data = JSON.parse(text);
        console.log('Parsed JSON:', data);
        // Assuming the response is valid, dispatch the sign-in success action and navigate
        dispatch(signInSuccess(data));
        navigate('/');
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('Could not sign in with Google', error);
      }
    };
  return (
    <button onClick={handleGoogleClick}type='button'className='bg-yellow-500 text-white p-3 rounded-lg uppercase hover:opacity-95'>Continue with google</button>
  )
}


is anyone having similar issues with their application i tried different browser's as well same issue
when trying different browsers issues remains the same.
